# NodeJs Codeception Docker: Cannot find module ‘chromedriver’ Image codeception/codecepjs 2.0.4

Tags: node.js, electron, e2e-testing, codeceptjs

I had Electron 1.7.5 running the tests with the codeception/codecepjs 1.0.1 image and chromedriver 2.38.3 normal but when I updated to electron 3.1.13 it started to break the tests.

I updated the codepcetion image to codeception/codecepjs 2.0.4 and started the chromedriver for 2.40.0 because it is compatible with electron chrominium but now I keep getting error in chromedriver:
Cannot find module ‘chromedriver’
I’ve tried to import in all ways but without success, follow the codes used. Help-me please.

## Dockerfile:

```
FROM codeception/codeceptjs:2.0.4
RUN npm install chromedriver@2.40.0 node-fetch@2.6.0 chai@4.2.0 --save-dev
```

## codecept.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  tests: './features/*.feature.js',
  timeout: 10000,
  output: './reports',
  helpers: {
    WebDriver: {
      smartWait: 10000,
      waitForTimeout: 10000,
      browser: 'chrome',
      url: 'localhost',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 9515,
      uniqueScreenshotNames: true,
      manualStart: true,
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
          binary: '/gateway/node_modules/.bin/electron',
          args: [
            'app=/gateway/',
            '--whitelisted-ips',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-extensions'
          ]
        }
      },
      timeouts: {
        script: 10000,
        pageLoad: 10000,
        implicit: 10000
      }
    },
    Simulator: {
      require: "./simulator.js"
    },
    App: {
      require: "./app.js"
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './actor.js'
  },
  bootstrap: './bootstrap.js',
  teardown: './teardown.js',
  mocha: {},
  name: 'rilix-gateway'
};
```

## Bootstrap(Where i used chromedriver):

```
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

const args = [
  '--url-base=wd/hub',
  '--port=9515'
];

module.exports = function (done) {
  chromedriver.start(args);

  (new Promise((resolve) => waitServer('http://api:9000', resolve)))
    .then(() => done());
};

function waitServer(url, done) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(() => done())
    .catch(() => setTimeout(() => waitServer(url, done), 1000));
}
```

## When I try run the tests(With Docker) i received this error:

```
Cannot find module 'chromedriver'

Error: 
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tests/bootstrap.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

I already tried to change the chromedriver version, import it in several ways, I tried to install chromedriver globally in the dockerfile but nothing changed this error in the chromedriver dependency.